# How to use LINQ Except() inside of a where clause

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I am having trouble with understanding how to correctly use Except(). **I would like to use Except() inside of a *where clause* to exclude results which match a list of strings**.  I made up the trivial example below to illustrate.

Also, is using Except in this case the fastest approach? If not, what would be faster?

**Where I have this:**

```
var result = (from FunTable in Context.t_FunTable

              where FunTable.ft_FunStartDate >= startDate
              && FunTable.ft_FunEndDate <= endDate

       ---->  && FunTable.ft_FunStage != notAllowedStage1 
       ---->  && FunTabble.ft_FunStage != notAllowedStage2

              select FunTable.ActivityName).ToList<String>();
```

**I would like to do this:**

```
var result = (from FunTable in Context.t_FunTable

              where FunTable.ft_FunStartDate >= startDate
              && FunTable.ft_FunEndDate <= endDate

      ---->   && FunTable.ft_FunStage.Except(ListOfNotAllowedStages)

              select FunTable.ActivityName).ToList<String>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Contains` instead:

```
!ListOfNotAllowedStage.Contains(FunTable.ft_FunStage)
```

Or `Any`:

```
!ListOfNotAllowedStage.Any(x => x == FunTable.ft_FunStage)
```

Comment: This works well. I find it counter-intuitive that my targets to exclude is written first, or am I a little crazy?

Comment: It is but having a LINQ method called `IsContainedIn` would likely be worse.

Comment: Speed for this would be O(n) correct? Can I optimize to O(1)?

Comment: @Ray `Except` would be definitely wrong choice in this case.And it looks like `ft_FunStage` is a single value, so you can not use `Except` as you wrote. Simply use `Contains` in these cases.It will be translated as `NOT IN` into `SQL`

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you want this:

```
&& !ListOfNotAllowedStages.Contains(FunTable.ft_FunStage)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is given by [Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700083/2642204), but to answer question directly one has to note that the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method is [not supported by the query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx). So if you really wanted to use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) you'd have to try something like this:

```
var result = (from FunTable in Context.t_FunTable
              where FunTable.ft_FunStartDate >= startDate
              && FunTable.ft_FunEndDate <= endDate)
             .Except(Context.t_FunTable
                 .Where(x => ListOfNotAllowedStages.Contains(x.ft_FunStage))))
             .Select(x => x.ActivityName);
```

As you can see it's a bit complicated, and thus this is not the best way to solve this problem. Adding a simple condition `!ListOfNotAllowedStage.Contains(FunTable.ft_FunStage)` to your `where` clause, as presented by [Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22), is the best solution.